# Teminate all running processes

Tags: javascript

How can I stop all processes (loops, timeouts, intervals, etc.) and separately remove event handlers?

I don't want to stop further execution, just stuff that's running.

Example Usage:

```
var i = 0;
for(;;){
  (i >= 20000)?StopExecution:i++;
}
```

Comment: By writing proper code that comes with control flags for pausing or breaking out of everything. Do you have an actual use case with code, or are you just curious about the general concept? (also, running where: the browser, nodejs scripts, something else...?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah but this is a lib, and I can't control the end users code.. I'll be using this in a browser.

Comment: Can you provide some code in order to know what someone has to deal with?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a library that can kill other people's code. If so: unless you have control of the JS engine itself, you can't. You might be able to shut off all intervals (because interval ids are just numbers, but most people don't use intervals because they're bad practice). And unless you control the code loading, you will not have access to the content of any closure so you won't be able to mess with other people's code that way.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Exactly that apart from the fact that my library loads new pages with AJAX and I don't want the old JS to remain "Alive"

Comment: I'd say it's the "old JS'" job to clean up after itself.

Comment: then you're out of luck and what you actually explicitly want is to reload the page with the "new content to load" information stored in localStorage or the like, and tap into that with your code as first thing. Even if you "stop" everything, the JS environment is guaranteed polluted if you just keep loading in more and more data instead of resetting it through a page reload.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If I reload the page, what's the point of using AJAX? Is it possible that I remove all of the existing code and then load the new page?

Comment: Wrong question, instead you need to answer: why are you using AJAX if your purpose is to clean out old state? Because AJAX can't do that, so AJAX is not the solution here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how does YouTube use AJAX to load pages without "polluting" the environment if it's not possible?

Comment: they own the entire environment and know exactly what they're loading in: their own data, and they've done the thing I and Felix King mention: clean up after themselves by using code that can already do that. Much like anyone else using ajax on their own website for their own data. If your post is for your own data on your own site, too, then your post needs to be amended to explain that, and then my first comment is going to be the only answer worth giving.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oh, that makes sense.. I guess I'll just use `clearInterval` to get rid of the Intervals and leave the rest.. Anyhow, Thanks!